# Reading text file into pandas which contains escape characters results in missing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a long list of regex patters that I want replace with in some text data, so I created a text file with all the regex patterns and the replacements I want for them, however, when reading this text file as a pandas dataframe, one particular regex pattern is missing in the dataframe. I tried to read it as a text file instead and build a pandas dataframe out of it but since some of the regex patterns contain "," in them, it becomes difficult to separate each line as 2 different columns.

the key(regex_pattern), value(the values I want to replace them with look as follows):

```
key,value
"\bnan\b|\bnone\b"," "
"^\."," "
"\s+"," "
"\.+","."
"-+","-"
"\(\)"," "
```

when I read this as a dataframe using the following lines of code,

```
normalization_mapper = pd.read_csv(f"{os.getcwd()}/normalize_dict.txt", sep=",")
```

[image: the dataframe generated]

I also tried the datatype argument as follows

```
dtype={'key':'string', 'value':'string'}
```

what I can't figure out is how to handle this `"\(\)"` missing pattern in the dataframe, pretty sure it's related to the escape character formatting by the pandas data reader, is there a way to handle this? Also, weirdly escape characters in other rows have no issues when reading the text file.

Comment: It's not reproducible. I mean `pd.read_csv(f"{os.getcwd()}/normalize_dict.txt")` works fine.

Comment: oh yeah, I realized that it must be some jupyter notebook related issue, because the same thing works fine on vscode and pycharm, but I spent half a day trying to figure out a bug that's not related to code :/0